# Forçar que pelo menos um campo seja obrigatorio

Tags: jquery, html, jquery.validate

Tenho 4 CheckBox no meu formulário `HTML`, estou trabalhando nas validações somente com `Jquery.Validate`, existe um modo de que eu defina que pelo menos 1 desses checBox esteja acionado?

Alguma propriedade do `validate`? Ou somente criando uma função na raça?

Achei alguma coisa sobre [aqui](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/check-that-at-least-1-checkbox-is-checked-using-jquery-validate-plugin) Aparentemente a solução parece pratica e viavel, so que no meu caso não tenho um nome para o grupo de checkedbox

Meu código está assim:

```
<td colspan="2">Você conversou com quem?
   <input type="checkbox" name="Diretor" id="Diretor" />Diretor
   <input type="checkbox" name="Vice" id="Vice" />Vice-Diretor
   <input type="checkbox" name="Coordenador" id="Coordenador" />Coordenador
   <input type="checkbox" name="Nenhum" id="Nenhum"  />Não conversei com ninguem
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o que precisa é o método [require_from_group](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method) que valida se um elemento num grupo estiver preenchido.

Na página do plugin (link em cima) tem esse exemplo:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    mobile_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    home_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    work_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    }
  }
});
```

#### No seu caso o código podia ser assim: http://jsfiddle.net/n1581gkx/1/

e precisa então de ter estes ficheiros carregados:

```
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: kkkk o que eu não gostei foi desse phone-group . . . ele vem da [biblioteca]?(http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio adaptei o jsFiddle para usar o seu HTML. Mas vai ter de juntar essa biblioteca sim.

Comment: da esse erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of null 
na linha 4 do jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio pode adaptar o meu jsFiddle com o seu código e colocar aqui um exemplo do jsFiddle com o erro?

Comment: velho, o problema é que aqui na empresa usamos bibliotecas padrões, não podemos ficar adaptando desse modo rs tipo, o jquery que usamos é o v1.4.2 ainda p.exp.... ai ficamos meio que presos com nossa tecnologia :(

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio então faça um validate customizado com JS simples... tipo `if( !$('.phone-group').filter(function(){ return this.checked; }) ) return false; // caso nenhum checkbox clicado`

Comment: adaptei alguns negocios aqui e aparentemente funcionou, enfim, agradecido velho :)